# How to generalize the notion of disjoint paths emanating from a point.

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I have proven something about a finite collection of disjoint rays emanating out from the same point in the plane (sets of the form $$\bigcup_{n=1}^N \left\{{(x_0,y_0) + t(x_n,y_n)}\; |\; 
t\geq0 \right\}$$
for some $(x_0,y_0),\dots,(x_N,y_N)$.

[image]

I think that this fact I'm proving should be true for any collection of paths emanating from a point, regardless of their shape, as long as they don't intersect. It doesn't matter that they are in the plane. They could be on a sphere or in higher dimensions, and they can even have an end point. However, you must turn around to get back to the starting points, e.g., no circular paths. I want to abstractly capture the idea of a collection of one dimensional paths with a common starting point. I'm trying to think of the correct concepts needed for that generalization.

My first idea is to define a topological space $X$ and a collection of subsets $A_n$ and a collection of homeomorphisms $f_n: I_n \to A_n$ where each $I_n$ is either $[0,1]$ or $[0,1)$ and $f_n(0)$ is the same for all $n$.

Am I on the right track or is there a more elegant way to do this? The only structure I need on the path is to be able to talk about one point being "further down the path" than another.

Comment: What's the need for the subsets $A_n$, are they just there to keep the paths disjoint?

Comment: I just can't think of any other way to define such a space without building each path first and gluing them together somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You may define a topological space $S_{m,n}$ which will be the model for a *star* with $m$ bounded and $n$ unbounded paths. Intuitively you build the space by gluing $m$ copies of $[0,1]$ and $n$ copies of $[0,\infty)$ along their respective zeroes. Formally you may do this by constructing the quotient space
$$S_{m,n}=\left(\bigsqcup \limits_{i=1}^m [0,1] \sqcup \bigsqcup \limits_{i=m+1}^{m+n} [0,1) \right)_{0_i \sim 0_j \forall i,j}$$

Now taking a continuous map $S_{m,n} \rightarrow X$ will give you a (generalized) star in $X$, possibly with self intersections. So you might want to use a continuous injection or an inclusion of a subspace instead…

**Edit** We can give an explicit model of $S_{m,n}$ as subspace of $\Bbb R^d$ (in fact $\Bbb R^2$). Let $v_1,…,v_{m+n}$ be nonzero pairwise linear independent vectors in $\Bbb R^2$. Then
$$S_{m,n} = \bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{m} \{ tv_i \mid t \in [0,1] \} \cup \bigcup \limits_{i=m+1}^{m+n} \{tv_i \mid t \in [0,1)\}$$

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I wonder if the easiest solution would be to just define such a star in R^n and then say "let X be any space that is homeomorphic to the star we just built."

Comment: This will work too. I think it’s a matter of taste wether you prefer parametrized constructions (as subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$) or coordinate-free ones (as limits / colimits of certain building blocks). In the former case, I added the easiest description I could think of to my answer.

Comment: Cool, I think your edit is the most straightforward/clear solution.